# Order Quantity Double after joining with delivery

Tags: sql, hana, sql-scripts

We can have multiple deliveries for single order item. So,when I am joining Order-Item with Delivery, I get multiple rows. Now, if I want to get order quantity at Order Item level ( not including Delivery-Item), I get wrong aggregation. I understand why query is behaving like that , but not sure how to make aggregation correct at each possible level of drill down .

[Order Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX711.png)

[Deliver Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LKwl.png)

[After joining Order and Deliv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBDgD.png)

[Result is Correct at Order ID,Item, Product level.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcUtY.png)

Comment: At Order ID, Order Item, Prod level it is working fine .. But Only product level gives me wrong sum ..

Comment: You should add  text table schema  .. data sample, actual result and expected  result  .. (not links to image only)

Comment: there is no way to understand what you want.  Please provide expected output along with sample data and query tried -- use text not pictures.

Comment: I tried to attach Sample Table , Query and Expected Result , but it is going as link ..

Comment: I don't understand what you want aggregated, and I don't understand what you mean when you say it's wrong.

Comment: @AustinMullins - if you see my result screenshot , data is correct . But if I run the same query at product level i.e choose only PRODUCT and Order Quantity, I would get wrong sum. I would expect 110 for the first two rows, but would get 60 because of the MAX function.

Comment: Can you replace the images you attached with code like in @Eralper's answer, and then show in text what output you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would approach this problem. From the looks of things your table does not look normalised to me. You have ORD_ID and ORD_ITM present in two tables. You should have this present only in you T_ORDER table then have the ORD_ITM present in your T_DELIV table. From the diagram you have also shown, you do not have an OrderItem_table so it will be confusing to help. But with my solution, just have your ORD_ITM only as a foreign key in your delivery table then join by this field. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is nice to have a normalized database, but I don't think that is preventing this join from working (for now).

Comment: @AustinMullins denormalization is a common  solution for performance problems, especially on column store

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with data you have provided

The product for Order 10001 item 30 is P2 in one table and P3 in the other

Could you please provide your sample data and table structure in the following format so others can help you easily

```
create column table T_ORDER (
ORD_ID int,
ORD_ITM int,
PROD varchar(5),
ORD_QTY int
);

create column table T_DELIV (
DELIV_ID int,
DELIV_ITM int,
ORD_ID int,
ORD_ITM int,
DELIV_QTY int,
PROD varchar(5)
);

insert into T_ORDER values (10001,10,'P1',50);
insert into T_ORDER values (10001,20,'P1',60);
insert into T_ORDER values (10001,30,'P2',40);
insert into T_ORDER values (10001,40,'P3',30);
insert into T_ORDER values (10002,50,'P4',20);


insert into T_DELIV values (50001,10,10001,10,20,'P1');
insert into T_DELIV values (50001,20,10001,10,30,'P1');
insert into T_DELIV values (50002,10,10001,20,60,'P2');
insert into T_DELIV values (50002,20,10001,30,30,'P3');
insert into T_DELIV values (50003,10,10001,40,10,'P3');
insert into T_DELIV values (50003,20,10001,40,15,'P3');
```

Comment: @ Eralper ...you are correct. Delivery Table has issue with Product  value . That is redundant information though , so should not affect final result. Basically , I am trying to build a HANA calculation view but unable to get right aggregation at every level of drill down possible.

Comment: Please provide sample data with above INSERT commands, so many developers here in the forum will be willing to help you with a solution asap

Comment: Eralper- Inserts statement provided by you works perfect for generating example data. I was able to resolve it by adding Order Quantity from Order table again to the result set of Order-Deliv join. Only thing I had to do is to put Order_ID and Order_ITM in "group by"  no matter whatever fields user selects in the final query . They way to do it in HANA modeling is to use "Keep Flag" .  Thanks for all the help .